# Django on eclipse "codec can't decode byte" "codec can't decode byte" error

Tags: django, eclipse

(Sorry about the images format, I didn't know that you can't post images/links if you are new.)

First of all, I've spent like 2 hours googling this Error, so I'm pretty sure that I'm not missing anything here.

How I got to this error is fairly simple: I need to use Django to develop a pretty simple application for college purposes. My first approach was to use PyDev on Eclipse (I've used Eclipse to code java for sometime, kinda like it a lot). I got 2 PCs here (Mine and My brother's one) and I did the SAME process on both. Here is what I did:

(I'm using Windos 7 64 bits)

- Downloaded and installed Eclipse 4.3 64 bits (the last version on this date);
- Downloaded and installed Pythong 3.3.2 64 bits (the last version on this date);
- Downloaded and installed Django 1.5.1.

This one(Django) was more tricky, because no .exe, no fun. So I've unziped Django and used the command "python setup.py install" on prompt. There was like thousands lines of "copying" and after sometime it finished with no errors.

So, I've opened Eclipse and created a new Django Project: (Link to album https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq5QP.jpg)

First Image

Second Image

Third Image

Actually, before that I've defined the path for the Interpreter:

Fourth Image

Fifth Image

And finally tested it, BUT:

Sixth Image

What really bugs me is tha fact that I did the SAME process on both PC, and I get no "Erro" on the other PC. Console gives me the same result, but with no Erro. And, of course, the server gets online. If I enter 127.0.0.1:8000 I get the "Django is working, Congratz !!!" on the browser. (My brother's pc is Windows 64 bits too)

On my PC, the sqLite3 server barely gets online, because the Erro occurs as soon as the server go up.

Any ideias ?

One thing that may help:

This is what I get if I let eclipse folder on the Desktop:

Seventh Image

After "MalformedByteSequenceExcepttion:" it is written "Byte inválido 2 da sequencia UTF-8 do byte 3", that means "Invalid byte 2 of the sequence of UTF-8 byte 3". If I change the directory of Eclipse folder to "C:/Program Files/Eclipse", I can configure the Interpreter without any problem.

My biggest doubt lies on: which one is causing the error ? OS, Django, Python, Path, any 32/64 bits conflict.

I saw many people complaining abaout Python encoding, but I'm not sure if this is Pythons fault.

HALP !

Comment: Django 1.5.x only has experimental Python 3 support. I would recommend sticking with 32-bit Python 2.7.x on Windows. I had all sorts of issues with 64-bit Python on Windows 7 Enterprise until I switched back to Linux.

Comment: Firstly I would try python2.7 as @Brandon stated. I would also check if there are non ascii characters within any of your file paths.

Comment: Well, I've tried with Python2.7/Django1.5.1 both 64 bits and it worked. I was reluctant with that option because the professor said we should use python 3.x. But there were major changes in some functions, like print "Hello !" nos is print("Hello !"), so I not sure if I can make Python 3.x compile a 2.x code.

But thanks for the help @Brando and MattWritesCode, much appreciate.

Comment: Thanks @MattWritesCode ! Stackoverflow helped me before a hundred times, but this is the first time post a question and this bureaucracy "overflow", like "too many links !" "too many photos !" "only one additional user !" is really annoying.

Comment: What are you needing to do that is Python 3 specific?

Comment: Actually is not a NEED. I belieave the professor chose 3.x just for standardization. @Brandon

Comment: Hmm. I would say that logic is fairly flawed. Django and many, many 3rd-party apps for Django are still Python 2.x only. Any dependency your project has that isn't Python 3.x compatible *automatically* means you're using Python 2.x

Comment: I totally agree with you. I'll try to convince the professor about the Python 2.x. I'm pretty sure he's not familiar with Django, as this is the first time he trys it on his Python classes. @Brandon

Comment: Yikes. Sounds like I need to get into teaching :)